# In ubuntu server, clear console when returning from application

Tags: command-line, server, console

In the console in Ubuntu Desktop, when I return from an application like Vim or Tasksel, it clears the application and the console picks up where it left off before the application started.

In Ubuntu Server, when returning from an application, the application is no longer running and I am back in the console, but what was last displayed of the application is still left on the console.

How can I get it to clear like it does in Ubuntu Desktop?

Edit: I am not looking for a command that I can use to clear, I am asking how could I get what was last displayed to clear automatically upon exit of the program.

Comment: What is the value of `TERM`? Try `echo $TERM`.

Comment: @muru. `echo $TERM` gives `linux`.

Comment: Give `byobu` a go. In TTY it allows the same behavior as in gnome-terminal (which is the default for Ubuntu Desktop you're referring to)

Comment: @Serg. Thanks. This was not exactly what I was looking for but it works as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Desktop is running a terminal emulator within the graphical display. Whereas, the server runs a virtual terminal in a console session. They both have different behaviours.

You will need to look in to the terminfo settings and possibly this previous post at superuser might help.

https://superuser.com/questions/136162/how-can-i-still-see-the-man-text-after-i-quit-man/136205#136205